# Saving and updating nested documents with MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I want to implement this structural model to store my data on Mongodb with MongoEngine on flask:

```
skills = [{"asm":"Assembly",
           "flag":False,
          "date": datetime},
          {"java":"Java",
           "flag":False,
           "date": datetime}]
```

So I don't know how I can declare and update this kind of structure.
For updating one object I used:

```
User.objects(skills=form.skills.data).update_one()
```

However, I don't know how to update more fields in one shot.
I tried with the code below but it doesn’t work.

```
now = datetime.now()
 User.objects(skills=form.skills).update_one(set__skills = ({'ruby':'Ruby'}, {'flag':'true'},{'date':now}))
```

What kind of fields should I declare on forms.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understood, you need a a nested document (skills) into another (who refers to User in this case). For doing something like this you don't have to update atomically a field but **append** values to the subdocument and the **save** everything.
Tryin' to follow your example, in your case should do something like this:

```
user = User.objects(email=current_user.email).get()
```

To get the BaseQuery that refers to user X through a certain query filter, in my example the email of the current logged user

```
user.kskills.append(SubDocumentClass(skillName="name_of_the_skill", status=True, date=datetime.now()))
```

For append a collection to the subdocument list. (I've appended your field)

```
user.save()
```

To save everything